# Cannot add win 7 pro to domain

Tags: windows-7, domain

I have a win 7 pro  device joined the domain, and then changed the server, domain, and I want to enter it again, but I could not as it appears at the top of the dialog box, contain it can not join a computer that uses Windows 7 Pro to domain

I need help

[image: the problem images]

Comment: have you tried joining a workgroup first? Then after that trying to join the domain. This is assuming you have already checked you have the correct DNS and ip settings

Comment: What server software are you running, there is an issue that might be relevant with 2008 SBS server

Comment: You remove the machine from the previous domain I presume and said server is not connected to the network currently

Comment: yes i join machine to workgroup but i cannot join to domain

Comment: DNS an ip setting is correct

Comment: i have win server 2012 R2